# Routing issue in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to change the URL and call html as desired

When i am at home page  my url should have login .

[Here is my plunker link too for reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/6OKA6VtH5qAFzygiS5RY?p=preview)

`run.plnkr.co/VqxyVuraDTBrBUbZ/` but i want the url as `**run.plnkr.co/loginPage**`

And if you will see my controller.js .If i able to succesfully login i should display  `dashboard.html` and url should `**run.plnkr.co/Dashboard**`
How can i achieve this ?

My routing config is as below

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('mainApp', ["ngRoute"]);
  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
                 .when("/main", {
                templateUrl: "index.html"
                 })

                .otherwise ( {redirectTo: "/"})
  })

}
());
```

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you got your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the corrected plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/c44XbwJ8JX7CPTdOIDae?p=preview)

Here are the changes made in router file

```
(function () {

  angular.module('mainApp')
   .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: './login.html',
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
      })
      .when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "dashboard.html"
      })
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/login" })
  })

}
  ());
```

Also, note that I have changed several other things like:

- `controller.js` name to `app.js`
- Proper implementation of `IIFE`