# Authenticate login information with Oracle database

Tags: java, angularjs, oracle, rest

I have created one login page using AngularJs .
How do i authenticate the user creditials that i have stored in the Oracle DB.

Probably through RESTful API.

I want to use following technology stack :
**Java
Hibernate**

Comment: make $http request and validate. You already have a form in your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49954639/routing-issue-in-angularjs . In case you need more details, put your code and your effort that you have put into before asking question :) Happy coding

Comment: thanks for the reply.As i mentioned i am new to JAVA.Can you just mention me the steps i need to follow like creating class etc.Or better point to some tutorial so i can get going.